# Link external raw file to hdf5 file with h5py

Tags: python, numpy, h5py, hdf

I work a lot with binary flat files and they need to remain in their current format to work with legacy codes, however I would also like to be able to use some of the features of HDF5 files with the attributes and groups. I see in the HDF5 [documentation 5.5.4](https://www.hdfgroup.org/HDF5/doc/UG/HDF5_Users_Guide-Responsive%20HTML5/index.html#t=HDF5_Users_Guide%2FDatasets%2FHDF5_Datasets.htm%23TOC_5_5_4_External_Storagebc-19&rhtocid=5.3.0_4) that external data can be linked in. Is there a straight-forward way to create the HDF5 files and add the external links with h5py?

Comment: Are you referring to `5.5.4. External Storage Properties`?  Looks like the key to using that is the `H5Pset_external` command.  If `h5py` does not give you access to that command, you many have to create the file with other `hdf5` utilities.

Comment: Thanks hpaulj. For some reason i can't look at that paged due to "banned content", but if that is the case I guess I will have to write my own tool using the c++ utilities then.

Comment: Try your own search on hfpy google groups, listed at http://docs.h5py.org/en/latest/contributing.html.  I'll delete the earlier comment.  I found a few posts dealing with 'external storage', but not many.

Comment: H5Pset_external is not currently exposed. https://github.com/h5py/h5py/issues/945

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your binary flat file contains 10000 float32 at a certain OFFSET in bytes in the file, and that you want to read them back into a 3D array data of shape (10, 20, 50) the code below should do the job

```py
input_file = "filename.raw"
output_file = "filename.h5"
offset = OFFSET
shape = (10, 20, 50)
size = 4 * shape[0] * shape[1] * shape[2] # 4 bytes per element

import h5py
import numpy
h5 = h5py.File(output_file, "w")
dataset = h5["/"].create_dataset("data",
                                 shape=shape,
                                 dtype=numpy.float32,
                                 external=((input_file, offset, size),))
h5.flush()
h5.close()
```

The `external` keyword expects multiple tuples of the form (filename, offset, size)  for the case the created dataset should be built with portions of different files or offsets.